# Regex using backreference with egrep when using nested bracket

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Problem: in short the question is how to use back reference when the brackets are nested in each other. 
Example
I have a the following:

```
213.321
.323
213.
```

It must match every real number with decimal point.It must not match wait any 
I have this regex which works for me!

> (()|([0-9]+)).(()|([0-9]+))

But I want to back reference to the OUTER bracket.

We see there are three bracket, so we can use the following back reference \1 or \2 or \3.

But really I want to back reference to the outer bracket.How it us possible to do or it is impossible to do ?

Also, if trying to use \1 or \2 or \3 it not works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a specific example of what you're trying to do. At the moment, it is unclear.

Comment: Can you include full example? For your example `\d+\.\d+` is enough.

Comment: match groups are counted each time a left paren is encountered. so for a nested set for example:  `((second)first(last))`

Comment: using \1 doesn't provide solution ^(()|([0-9]+))\.\1

Comment: The outer bracket IS `\1`. Clarify your question with concise, testable sample input and expected output, a better explanation of what you're trying to do, and details about in what way using `\1` "doesn't provide solution" - wrong output, no output, error messages, core dump, something else? Also tell us which version of `egrep` you are using (and stop using it is it's deprecated, use `grep -E` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regular expression `(()|([0-9]+)).(()|([0-9]+))`, the following are the the various groups:

```
(()|([0-9]+)).(()|([0-9]+))
12  3         45  6
```

Both `\2` and `\5` will always be empty. The outer groups are referenced by `\1` and `\4`.